# Javascript module pattern and empty objects

Tags: javascript, module, module-pattern

When using the Module pattern to extend a module we do something like this:

```
var NewModule = (function (Main) {

    Main.extension = function () {};
    return Main;

})(Main || {});
```

That works great and the question is, if Main is not declared we avoid errors by passing an empty object `Main || {}`. How do we prevent this dependency from breaking? Granted, we wont have any errors at first but if we are not able to attach our extension to Main we will encounter other type of errors.

Comment: Is the desire to occasionally call it with no arguments and get an object with the extension methods?

Comment: probably better ways of doing it but my immediate feeling is just, i'm guessing, either a) fatal err if your root dependency is missing (rather than ignoring it and passing an empty object) or b) check for missing dependencies everywhere else with the roots siblings

Comment: @RobM. That is correct, the main goal is for `Main` to have all the methods available when needed in the future.

Comment: @mad.meesh, yeah I thought about having a hard stop if `Main` object is not present at the application level but yet again leave some sort of flexibility for unit testing.

Comment: ah if this issue is specific to unit testing then i believe you need to solve this with 'mock objects' and such, have you already consider this? also another way of saying it is to build your abstractions based on behavior (interfaces)

Comment: I agree with @mad.meesh that it would be better to not swallow errors, that should prevent users from incorrectly calling `NewModule`. Not sure exactly how you are unit testing this, but passing in an empty object and verifying that the extension methods have been added seems sufficient (at least from the outside with limited context)

Comment: Thanks for the input, the more I think about it the more I am inclined to solve some of these problems with process. The fear of having bug reports because one of the extensions was not created and attached properly is having me over engineer the solution and create stop gaps in the wrong places which code reviews and process can solve. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to *extend* `Main`, you usually wouldn't assign to `NewModule`. You'd rather do

```
// a.js
var Main = (function (localMain) {
    localMain.extensionA = function () {};
    return localMain;
})(Main || {});
```

We do this so that we can have multiple modules like that:

```
// b.js
var Main = (function (localMain) {
    localMain.extensionB = function () {};
    return localMain;
})(Main || {});
```

All of them will either *create or extend* the `Main` object, so that it doesn't matter in which order they load - both `a.js, b.js` and `b.js, a.js` will work. The pattern is also sometimes simplified to

```
(function (localMain) {
    localMain.extension = function () {};
})(Main = Main || {});
```

(although that lacks the `var` declaration).

If your module (especially your newModule) does have an actual *dependency* on the main module, and requires that it was loaded before it is executed, you would not use this defaulting pattern.